# react-google-recaptcha not showing up

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

```
  <form className='confession-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div className="form-group">
        <div className="select-box">
            <div className={this.state.selectOptionActive ? 'options-container active' : 'options-container'}>

                <div className="option" onClick={this.selectOption}>
                    <input type="radio" name="category" id="dream" className="cat-radio" />
                    <label htmlFor="dream">Dream</label>
                </div>

                <div className='option' onClick={this.selectOption}>
                    <input type="radio" name="category" id="guilt" className="cat-radio" />
                    <label htmlFor="guilt">Guilt</label>
                </div>

                <div className='option' onClick={this.selectOption}>
                    <input type="radio" name="category" id="pain" className="cat-radio" />
                    <label htmlFor="pain">Pain</label>
                </div>

                <div className="option" onClick={this.selectOption}>
                    <input type="radio" name="category" id="wild" className="cat-radio" />
                    <label htmlFor="wild">Wild</label>
                </div>

                <div className="option" onClick={this.selectOption}>    
                    <input type="radio" name="category" id="regret" className="cat-radio" />
                    <label htmlFor="regret">Regret</label>
                </div>

                <div className="option" onClick={this.selectOption}>
                    <input type="radio" name="category" id="fantasy" className="cat-radio" />
                    <label htmlFor="fantasy">Fantasy</label>
                </div>

                <div className="option" onClick={this.selectOption}>
                    <input type="radio" name="category" id="other" className="cat-radio" />
                    <label htmlFor="other">Other</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="selected" onClick={() => this.setState({selectOptionActive: !this.state.selectOptionActive})}>
                {
                    this.state.optionSelected ? (
                        this.state.optionSelected
                    ) : (
                        'Select Category'
                    )
                }
                <span className={this.state.selectOptionActive ? 'mdi mdi-chevron-up' : 'mdi mdi-chevron-down'}></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <textarea name="confession" id="confession" className='confession-body' placeholder='What is your confession?'></textarea>
    
    <ReCAPTCHA className="recaptcha" sitekey={process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_KEY} size="normal" />
    
    <button className='btn-confess'>Confess</button>
```

i have this react class compenet with  a react-google-recaptcha
if i keep refreshing it sometimes the recaptcha doesn't show up.
and also if a navigate to my form page from home page then back to home then back to form page again it recaptcha doesnt show up and also i check  the inspect element the component recaptcha is only  (empty div with a class recaptcha)